# Object doesn't support this property or method. Why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I run this code on IE8 or lower, I get this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method`

```
var hasFlash = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```

Comment: have you tried to decompose it and see exactly where the problem is?

Comment: The debugger doesn't write anything else, just this error

Comment: Try inserting some line-breaks to find the part that is causing the troubles...

Comment: please check the  security-settings if signed  ActiveX-controls are allowed in the current security-zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `new ActiveXObject` part is failing, because `ActiveXObject` is (in your current setup) not anything that the `new` operator can be applied to -- or 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash' isn't a valid input and therefore an exception is thrown.

You can however easily rewrite your code to address that problem:

```
var hasFlash = (function() {
    if (typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") {
        return true;
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
        try {
            new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
            return true;
        } catch (e) { }
    }

    return false;
})();
```